# find image tutorial

Tags: java, image, image-processing

When I start to use the java 2D API to handle some image, I found that there are some classed I can not know how to use even read the api. I think it is caused by my poor knowledge about the image it self, so I wonder if there is any document about image?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are just getting started with the Java 2D API, lots of reading and playing is in order.  I don't know your level of familiarity with this, so here are a few links that might help get you started:

Java 2D API info from Oracle:

http://java.sun.com/products/java-media/2D/index.jsp

Many books can be found, such as [this one](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0130351180)

There are also numerous articles that will help with specific issues related to Java 2D.

https://web.archive.org/web/1/http://blogs.techrepublic%2ecom%2ecom/programming-and-development/?p=534

Finally, Oracle also has some tutorials you may find interesting.

http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/2d/index.html

Beyond all this, go ahead and start to play with it.  Then if you have specific technical questions, a direct answer will be easier to put together.

Comment: Thanks, I have read the Java Tutorial,the Java2D API enhancement,and etc.
Also I found some other paper about the stroke. the paint , the composite and etc. So I am familiarity with most of the basic 2D API 
Now I have to work with the image(BufferedImage),however I found that I can not understand some Professional terms,for example, a BufferedImage contain a SampleMOdel, DataBuffer, what is called Sample? How does the color make up a image? This is what I wanted./